# How to Get All Data for Using Linkedin company updates plugin in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I am using LinkedIn company updates plugin by WordPress,

but I have a problem this message see  in my problem

```
{
  "errorCode": 0,
  "message": "Member does not have permission to get company.",
  "requestId": "AHGJBG9I1A",
  "status": 403,
  "timestamp": 1542091847167
}
```

Please step by step learn to get author post data for LinkedIn.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the company details from LinkedIn you should make an authenticated request(You should be the administrator of the company). For authenticated calls follow this link.

https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/oauth2#

Comment: Which plugin you are using?

Comment: I Also Remember This Url And I Watch, I Get Api Url But Not Get Data.                                   Plugin Url : https://wordpress.org/plugins/company-updates-for-linkedin/

Comment: Did you follow these steps as plugin suggested https://wordpress.org/plugins/company-updates-for-linkedin/#installation

Comment: Yes I Follow This Steps But I Have No Get This Data.